# unknown error code during application install: "-504"

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

unknown error code during application install: **-504**

Actually i try to install an android app in **LAVA android Phone** with OS **version is 6** but Downloaded app is not installing in my device.

**Updat 1:** I done all basic cleanup and all

**update 2:** Checked with device comparability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Methods to solve error 504**

**Method 1:**

Go to Settings>> Application Manager or Apps>> Open “All” apps
From the list of apps find Google Play store >>Clear Data and Clear Cache
From the list of apps find Google Service Framework >> Clear Data and Clear Cache
Now install or update app from Google Play Store

**Method 2:**

Go to system settings>> Accounts>>Google>>remove your Gmail account
Now from settings>>Apps>>All> Force stop, Clear data and cache for Google Play Store, Google Service Framework and Download Manager (like in method 1)
Now again go to settings>> Accounts>>Google>>Add your gmail account
Restart your android and then accept all the Google terms and setup Google settings
Rerun Google Play Store and update or install your app.

**Method 3:** Installing a VPN app

Install Hideman VPN app from Google Play Store
Now open the app and select US as the country of connection and press connect
Open Google Play Store and Download app

These error 504 fixes should work for Google Play Store errors. If any suggestion or problem, please comment below with you smartphone model.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when you are trying to download and updating the `app`

***To solve this problem***

**Method 1:**

- Google play store
- Google play service

If you see google services framework ,Download manager Clear their and Data as Well

- If you are updating an App then try to clear their Data and cash.
- Remove your Google Account and Re-create it.

If you have more then **one google account** :

1. Go to `settings > Accounts > and than Google`
2. Remove yours all Google accounts
3. Open Play Store and add Accounts again

Restart your device and try to install or update the application

**Method 2:**

Check your **Date, time** and also **Time Zone** if its not correct then Please correct it and try to install app and update.

**Method 3:**

Uninstall the updates of google play store if you have it.

- `Go to Settings > Apps > Uninstall Play store updates`

**Method 4:**

This method requires your phone to be `Rooted`

If you had **installed** app before and **unistalled** app without clearing its `cash` and `Data`, there might be change some files are leftover.

1. Allow installing Apps from **unknown resources**
2. Go to apkmirror.com and do search for **Es File Explorer** Download it and install it
3. Enable Root Explorer
4. Go to `device/data/app`
5. If you see the folder of the app that you trying to install,**Just Delete it**
6. Restart your device and try to install or update the application

Hope this will be work for you.